# wine fixme wait_for_withdrawn_state window

Tags: docker, wine, xvfb

I am running a Windows execuable (`.exe`) using wine, in a docker container and I am dumping the graphical interface using `xvfb-run`. The setup is working but with some fixmes and some errors which I am trying to understand what do they mean.

The most common and fixme is:

```
002c:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x1004a/e00001 wait timed out
0024:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x10086/a00003 wait timed out
```

I found [here](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=30411&p=115241) that it means that:

> Your application X Windows are possibly staying in a Withdrawn (aka limbo) state - because Wine isn't drawing to the correct X (Xvfb) Display.

However I do not understand what is this withdrawn state and why wine isn't drawing to the corrcect X. Furthermore the same fixme is present when running wine with xvfb locally without docker.

Thank you!

---

The whole log from the docker-xvfb-wine setup:

```
$ xvfb-run --server-num=99 wine my.exe (runs using a run.sh specified by the CMD clause in the dockerfile) 
0050:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
002c:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x1004a/e00001 wait timed out
wine: configuration in L"/root/.wine" has been updated.
0024:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x10086/a00003 wait timed out
0024:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x1007c/a00001 wait timed out
X connection to :99 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

The log from the xvfb-wine setup (without docker):

```
$ xvfb-run --server-num=99 wine my.exe
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0048:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0048:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0050:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0050:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00cc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00cc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:freetype_set_outline_text_metrics failed to read full_nameW for font L"Ani"!
0024:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x20044/c00003 wait timed out
0024:fixme:event:wait_for_withdrawn_state window 0x1007a/c00001 wait timed out
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":99"
      after 19 requests (19 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to start a window manager, like bspwm.

```
Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99
bspwm &
wine some.exe
```